# How do I let a user paste an image on a webpage?

Tags: javascript

I want to give the user possibility to paste an image into a webform. I don't need to display the image, all I need is the image's location.

I know it's possible because the guys at CKEditor(and other editors) are doing it.

If you go here, http://ckeditor.com/demo and paste an image you copied and then right click on it and go to image properties you'll see they have the image's address.

How can this be done?

Thanks

Comment: How thrilling. It pastes a broken image icon.

Comment: I tried pasting in Firefox and got this message: "Because of your browser security settings, the editor is not able to access your clipboard data directly. You are required to paste it again in this window." As a feature, it doesn't seem that portable. My understanding is that the only reliable access to clipboard is using Flash (and I'm not sure if this allows anything other than text)

Comment: @David Dorward - Yes, you get a broken image icon, but if you look in the "Image properties" you'll see they have the image's location(which is the thing I need).


@spender - Try pasting using 'ctrl+v'

Comment: OK... ctrl+v behaves differently. What possible use is the local file location to a webapp though?

Comment: I want to create a Greasemonkey script that allows users to paste files inside a <input type="file"> element. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @b2238488 wansn’t my answer useful? It has been long since I answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible because giving a browser the possibility to access local files, which have not been added to be uploaded explicitly by the user, opens a variety of very dangerous security holes that would certainly be super-exploited by hackers.

A good solution would be to give the posibility to upload using Ajax and link the images in the document once they are available in the server.

Take a look at [“Sending files using a FormData object” part of the Using XMLHttpRequest document at Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Sending_files_using_a_FormData_object).